# Is there a word that can exactly express "to divide something into two parts'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that can contain such meaning?

Comment: Bifurcate, bisect, halve, hemisect.

Comment: What's the something?

Comment: There's always "divide".  Or apportion equally.  This must be a very good use to put  a dictionary and a thesaurus.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking for synonyns of [**halve**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/halve) or [**bisect**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bisect).

Answer (score -1):

As the other answer says, *halve* and *bisect* are good candidates. Other synonyms from WordNet dictionary are:

- biramous
- branched
- forked
- fork-like
- forficate
- pronged
- prongy
- furcate
- separate
- ramify

Comment: Yes, but those words are mostly adjectives. The questioner wanted a verb.